# The use of ForeingKey on django when I create an object is also creating an object from the foreignkey model

Tags: python, django

I have a function on the main app of the website i'm working on that creates a User - the model name is "Usuario" (different from the default User model that django provides). The model is:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    data_cadastro = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    telefone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True) # validators deve ser uma lista
    renda = models.DecimalField(default=0,max_digits=14,decimal_places=2)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(default=0,max_digits=20,decimal_places=12)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(default=0,max_digits=20,decimal_places=12)
```

(the names of the fields are in Portuguese)

This model is connected to a different one in another app by a simple foreing key (usuario). The other model is:

```
from core.models import Usuario
class Simulacao(Usuario):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, related_name="Usuario_contas", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data_simulacao = models.DateTimeField(default=now, verbose_name="Data simulação")
    tem_conta = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Simulação'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Simulações'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome
```

The function where I create the "Simulacao" object is this one:

```
from .models import Simulacao, Tipo_Pessoa
from core.models import Usuario
from django.utils.timezone import now

def cadastro_simulacao(form, email):
    nova_simulacao = Simulacao.objects.create(usuario = Usuario.objects.get(email = email), tem_conta=form['tem_conta'])
    usuario.Usuario_contas_set.add(nova_simulacao)
    usuario.save()
```

All i've done is based on the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

I have also tried the function like that:

```
from .models import Simulacao, Tipo_Pessoa
from core.models import Usuario
from django.utils.timezone import now

def cadastro_simulacao(form, email):
    nova_simulacao = Simulacao.objects.create(usuario = Usuario.objects.get(email = email), tem_conta=form['tem_conta'])
    nova_simulacao.save()
```

However, when it's done, a new object of "Usuario" is created with no information (no email, etc, all fields are created blank) and the information of the user doesn't appear properly at the "simulacao" model - the information that was supposed to be inherited from the "usuario" shows up blank too. 
Why is that happening? What I want is to catch the information of the User that has the same email and create a "simulacao" object that is connected to this user. I don't want a new object of user. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Simulacao inherits from Usario. It shouldn't do that; you have a separate ForeignKey. Remove that inheritance so that Simulacao inherits directly from models.Model.